# How to discretize Laplacian near refinement boundary

Tags: laplacian

Given a block structured grid with a refinement factor of two, what are some of the common ways to discretize a Laplacian near a refinement boundary? See also the picture below, in which $u_H$ and $u_h$ indicate coarse and fine values with the given indices. I'm particularly interested in the computation of $\nabla^2 u$ on the 'fine' side of the boundary.

Ideally, I would like to have a discretization that is second order accurate with as small a stencil as possible. A conservative discretization would also be valuable, meaning that the 'fluxes' $\nabla u$ on the fine and coarse side of the boundary match.

[image: Cell-centered values near a refinement boundary]

Answer (score 1):

I think one option is to interpolate $u$ to the left face of (3,1) first. Then you can use a modified Laplacian stencil to take into account the half-distance between $u$ at (3,1) and $u$ on the face.

Comment: It's indeed convenient to do this in two steps (first interpolate, then compute Laplacian), although this is equivalent to using a wider stencil that includes the coarse values used in the interpolation. But my question is about what particular discretizations are commonly used.

Comment: Ah, I see. This may depend on the equation you're solving, and what properties, if any, you hope that the discretization preserve.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit with that information

Comment: @JannisTeunissen , I think the answer I gave is a "common [way] to discretize a Laplacian near a refinement boundary", second order accurate and conserves flux. It may be difficult to further answer your question unless you specify that you need more numerical diffusion or something. In addition, this can be performed in one step, but more storage may be required to do so.

Comment: Could you describe how you would do the interpolation to get a second order accurate or conservative discretization? I've posted this question with the hope that somebody already has given this problem much thought.